# Synology NAS on WLAN

Tags: wireless-networking, lan, wireless-access-point, synology, synology-diskstation

I currently have my NAS connected to my network using an Ethernet cable to a Devolo PLC (Power-line communication). Works fine.

However, I need to move it to a location where the PLC connection is very bad. So I'd like to connect it to a WLAN (WIFI 6) that is accessible there.

I read somewhere that WIFI USB keys don't work anymore or won't work anymore soon (with DSM 7), so I'm looking for an access point to connect the NAS's RJ45 to the WIFI 6 network. I saw that this could be performed with access points, but **in client mode**.  However, all the access points I found do not specify in their documentation if they support "client mode", so I assume that they do not support it.

Does anyone know a WIFI (preferably WIFI 6) access point that supports "client mode", that I could buy?  I'm not experienced and don't want to make a mistake.

Comment: Asking for product recommendations is off topic here

Comment: You're might be welcome giving some examples and ask if we can find the feature in any of them. Some manufacturers calls that different names, but we are not familiar with "good WIFI AP" within your unknown price-range.

Comment: @RohitGupta Indeed, I paid special attention  writing something clear, and forgot that.
Eexamples : Netgear WAX214-200EUS, or Netgear WiFi 6 AX1800 PoE

Comment: @RohitGupta or Ubiquiti UniFi 6 Lite (or Pro), TP-Link Omada EAP650.

Comment: @Netan I would say less than $300, which is not IMHO a big constraint for an AP client mode.  Already at this price, it would be taking a Rolls to go shopping for the week at the supermarket.

Comment: That's probably your problem; you're looking at MESH solutions instead of a regular AP.

Comment: For example, even the simpler models on tp-link's website can support "Range Extender Mode" and "Client Mode" ( which, both should handle what you're looking for ). Look here, at the top of page number 9 and middle of 10: https://static.tp-link.com/upload/manual/2022/202209/20220916/191003248_TL-WA1201_UG_REV3.0.0.pdf